# xsl fo list of effective pages

Tags: xsl-fo

Does anyone know how to make a list of effective pages using xsl fo? I cant seem to find a way to do it. There does not seem to be a way to access all of the pages in the document. If anyone knows of any way to do it please let me know, thanks

Comment: What XSL-FO processor are you using?

Comment: Im actually using arbortext styler, it uses a gui interface to style a document but you can also go into the actual fo code and make edits. That being said im not sure exactly which processor it uses. I used to use XEP but I couldnt figure out how to do it on there either. Im thinking it must involve multiple passes

Comment: I use XEP and have created LEP's in the past. I did use 2 passes. I created the LEP based on XEP's intermediate file. I wanted to figure out a less time consuming way, but never had the time. How complicated are your page numbers? Do you have multiple pages sizes (foldouts)?

Comment: No nothing like foldouts. For a time the page numbers are in the usual 1,2,3 format, and then they go into 1000,2000,3000, up to 10000. What did you obtain from the intermediate file that allowed you to create the loep in the second pass? It seems that the only thing that allows you to see what page something is on is the <fo:page-citation> element, and this obviously is not any help